# AH00526: Syntax error from .DS_Store

Tags: apache

I've been getting the following error when I start apache server from terminal, which it was working yesterday.

AH00526: Syntax error on line 15 of /etc/apache2/.DS_Store:
Invalid command '\x01', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

I'm running server from mac yosemite.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know if it's the right answer, but the .DS_Store is an hidden file that we have inside all folders on Mac. If you use a FTP tool and send files to your server, file by file, you will not send this file. But if you send a full folder (eg. using drag and drop with Fetch), these hidden files will be sent. It seems there is no way to avoid it's tranmission.
I suggest to open the folder of your server using Fetch and you'll see all the .DS_Store file. Just delete them.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Peter. Unfortunately removing .DS_Store did not work. I also the codes in httpd to ignore .DS_Store files. Not sure why the server is still serving that file. The syntax error is referring to <VirtualHost *:80>

Comment: Maybe here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TOMEE-23
Notice that, as you are running Apache on your Mac, you can't really destroy the DS_Store file as Mac OS will create them again and again. Question: are you running Apache alone in order to have a real web server or are you using it under MAMP?

Comment: I'm running Apache alone. The last person with this machine did the setup and it was working fine until this week. I have code below to ignore .ds_store  `<FilesMatch "^\.([Hh][Tt]|[Dd][Ss]_[Ss]|[_])">`